# How to extract string between numbers? (And keep first number in the string?)

Tags: python, regex, text, text-mining, changelog

I am trying to extract data from a change log using RegEx. Here is an example how the change log is structured:

```
96545
this is some changes in the ticket
some new version: x.x.22
another change
new version: x.y.2.2
120091
this is some changes in the ticket
some new version: z.z.22
another change
another change
another change
new version: z.y.2.2
120092
...
...
...
```

- Each data point starts with an ID which has a range of 5 to 6 digits.
- Moreover there is a variable amount of changes (lines) in the log per ID.
- Each data point ends with `new version: ***`. `***` is string which is variable for every ID.

I was using the [RegExStrom Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test my RegEx.

So far I have: `^\w{5,6}(.|\n)*?\d{5,6}` however the result includes the ID from the next ticket, which I need to avoid.

Result:

```
96545
this is some changes in the ticket
some new version: x.x.22
another change
new version: x.y.2.2
120091
```

Expected Result:

```
96545
this is some changes in the ticket
some new version: x.x.22
another change
new version: x.y.2.2
```

Comment: `(?sm)^\d{5,6}.*?(?=^\d{5}|\Z)`? Why do you use Regexstorm if this regex is going to be used in Python? Use https://regex101.com/r/i53Qzw/1 to test the regex.

Comment: Also, why didn't you use `\nnew version:` as the right hand delimiter since you mention it in the pattern requirements? Try `(?sm)^\d{5,6}.*?\nnew version:[^\r\n]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem was that you capture the ID of the next Ticket just use positive look ahead to mach it but not capture it, or consume it:

```py
# end of tickets is the end of line that the line after it contains the Id of the next ticket
pattern = r"\d{5,6}[\s\S]*?(?=\n\d{5,6})"

# to extract first ticket info just use search
print(re.search(pattern, text).group(0))

# to extract all tickets info in a list use findall
print(re.findall(pattern, text))

# if the file is to big and you want to extract tickets in lazy mode
for ticket in re.finditer(pattern,text):
    print(ticket.group(0))
```

Comment: Hello Charif, thank you very much, that helps a lot. 

However now I am facing another issue. I am trying to append each log to its corresponding ticket using pandas, which are in a ```.csv``` file. 
```In: ids.head(2) | Out: {'Index': [0, 1], 'id': [96545, 120091 ]}... ```. By looping through the rows, I tried appending each found regex ticket to a cell next to the id. However I am getting the same regex text in each row. ```search = []   for values in ids['id']:  search.append(re.findall(pattern, text))   ids['tickethist'] = search ``` How can I append each found regex element?

Comment: You ca n edit your question and add the code to understand what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Captures each records ID in group 1 and content in group 2

`r'(?ms)^(\d{5,6}\r?\n)(.*?)^new version:'`

https://regex101.com/r/A3ejjN/1

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
^\d{5,6}[\r\n]*.*?^new version:[^\r\n]*
```

Just make sure to enable the `MULTILINE` and `DOTALL` flags via `re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL`

https://regex101.com/r/YeIUQx/1

Comment: I think `/^\d{5,6}[\r\n]*.*?^new version:[^\r\n]*/gms` is rather a confusing way of sharing Python regex. You can't use regex literals in Python. Besides, it does not support the global modifier, there are specific `re` methods that handle that part.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can see your point, I've edited that part out.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is close. Its issue is that it's "ending" at the start of the next log, by using `\d{5,6}` to mark the end of a log entry (and matching it in the process). As Wiktor mentioned, it would make more sense to use "new version" as the delimeter, so I've done that here.

`found_matches = re.findall("(^\d{5,6}[\s\S]*?^new version: .*$)", log_file_content, re.MULTILINE)`

The regex `(^\d{5,6}[\s\S]*?^new version: .*$)` searches for 5 or 6 digits at the start of the line, and then takes any character (including newlines) up until the first instance of `new version:` that appears at the start of a line. It then reads to the end of the line to finish that group. Since you're going to be matching across newlines, be sure to remember the `re.MULTILINE` argument!

Test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/vPknQY/1/), and the full python code [here](https://repl.it/repls/PlayfulBeneficialDiscussion).